# What is the name for a distributive lattice with only two elements, top and bottom?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

Is there a name for a distributive lattice with only two (nonequal) elements, **1** and **0**, corresponding to top and bottom, respectively? I was thinking of calling it a *trivial lattice*, but a trivial lattice should probably just have one element.

Comment: I'd call it the trivial bounded lattice myself, since bounded lattices by definition have a top and bottom element. (The single element lattice would be degenerate in that case)

Comment: Some call it $\mathbf 2$, and in general, $\mathbf n$ to a $n$-element chain.

Comment: The free lattice on 0 elements

Answer (score 2):

For a *name*, I would use *the two-element chain*. Grätzer uses this at least nine times in his book *Lattice Theory. Foundation* (Birkhäuser/Springer 2011).

Common *notations* are $C_2$ (used by Grätzer) and $\mathbf{2}$ (used by Stanley in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1).